# Facebook Webhook Url verification is returning with additional string on botman studio

Tags: php, laravel, botman

I am trying to verify my webhook url, however I am getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d066T.png)
Here is my code:

```
$config = [

   'facebook' => [
          'token' => 'page-token',
                'app_secret' => 'app-secret',
                'verification' => env('VERIFY_TOKEN')
     ]

 ];

   DriverManager::loadDriver(FacebookDriver::class);
    
   $botman = BotManFactory::create($config);   


   $botman->listen();
```

As noticed aboved I am getting additonal string added on the hub_challenge request. How will I able to solved this problem?